# Fat boostrap header on 'middle' and larger viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hope you can help - I left this issue on the backburner for a while now. It started when I was trying to recolor the default bootstrap navbar...but then I got in a mess and removed all the css to go back to default....and now the navbar toggle icon for the mobile size viewport has disappeared (it still exists but I can't seem to find why it's invisible(!). I've tried fiddling around with CSS to 'color' it but I'm having no luck...

Thanks in advance!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">      
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->    
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">     
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="store.php">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="forum.php">Feedback</a></li> 
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>  
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>User<span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>   
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>                  
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS for .navbar-toggle has transparent values set for the color of the toggle button.

```
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

See how both "background-color" and "border" are both transparent?  That means they're invisible.  Add some color to these selectors and I think you'll be on your way.

Like so:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
  /* GIVE THE BARS SOME COLOR TOO */
 .icon-bar {
   background: white;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/7auryr4f/)

Comment: Thanks very much @ben.kaminski - I can see it!

Comment: No problem Bendy... glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can control background color like this

```
.navbar-header{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8983/

Comment: Thanks @Gorostas... Embarrassing that it was something so trivial though